# [mutual]ly assured destruction

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [mutual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutual) tag (3 followers, 55 questions) should be burninated.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   It does, but it fails the ambiguity test. There is already [mutual-exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutual-exclusion), [mutual-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutual-recursion) and [mutual-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutual-authentication) that covers about 80% of the existing questions, and [circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference) (perhaps a [mutual-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutual-reference) synonym is needed) covers many of the remaining, but there also needs to be a new [mutual-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutual-relationship) to cover SNS mutual friend questions.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   As noted above, with tag specialisation, it is on-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Same answer as for 2.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   No, as pointed out above, it is a bit too vague on its own without specialisation.

I'll start myself by cleaning up at the edges and retagging with the more specific tags mentioned in 1.

**Update**:
All questions have been retagged.

Comment: +1 for the great title. It's a funny pun, contains the tag, and clearly implies burnination. (and I guess the tag should go, too)

Comment: And it's burninated already. That was fast

Comment: So... selective comments getting deleted because?

Comment: Yeah, the comment deletion on this one is a bit over the top. Do we really need to be this aggressive deleting comments on meta? I realize that they didn't add much in the way of value, but this is one of the places where a little bit of fun is allowed.